# nested .htaccess rewrite rule only works on some servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

we have a piece of software running on many differnet servers, where do not have access to apache configuration. Sometimes we are running into the following problem:

We have a .htaccess file within our software, which defines a rewrite rule:

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
...
```

which rewrites requests to an index.php at the current directory.

On some systems this gives us some trouble. The only solution we have found so far is to change the rule to

```
RewriteRule . <path relative to webroot>/index.php [L]
```

I do not understand why we have this problem, and I would love to have a solution that works in both variants.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This line `RewriteRule . <path relative to webroot>/index.php [L]`

first part after `RewriteRule` is pattern which is `.` in your rule .

The second part named Substitution which is `<path relative to webroot>/index.php` in your rule.

The last part is flag which is `[L]`  in your rule

From apache documentaion :

> The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. The Substitution may be a: file-system path,URL-path
>   ,Absolute URL or - (dash).

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

So , according to your structure you could use the one that satisfy your need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, bu tI do not see how this might help us.
The <path relative to webroot> changes on each server, tht is why we used the first since it rediretced to the index.php in the same folder. 
So we have a variing URL-path, a variing Absolute Url (different servers) and variing  file-system path